# Exporting Part of a CoreData database

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an application that has a core data database maintaining its info.
Obviously I have a `managedObjectModel` and a `persistentStoreCoordinator` managing the application's data.

I would like to export a small subset of it as a separate file/store (via another coordinator?) so that it can be sent/emailed to someone else with the same application and opened and merged into their contents.

Obviously, the merge part has sticky possibilities, but I'm ready for that.  Anyone else have pointers, suggestions, experiences on tricks, traps, or best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to do this at the database level.  Core Data's database is merely an implementation issue...it could change in the future, and you should not rely on the database directly.  Instead, take the objects (objects, not database entries) that you want to share, serialize them to some transmission format (like JSON or NSCoder), and decode it on the receiver's end.

Comment: that seems like and arbitrary statement - there are many document based applications that use core data as storage.  the database format will not change more often than my data model (which is versioned).  NSCoder encoded files are just as susceptible to versioning issues as core data.  not to mention … (iOS 5.0 NDA comment here)

Answer (score 0):

You can mesh together an arbitrary number or persistent stores and models together in one context. The only major limitations is that (1) you can't have entities of the same name in different models and (2) you can't form relationships across stores.

In your case, you would most likely use one model and two stores. You assign different entities to different stores using the configuration property (see the docs.) I would suggest creating a "main" configuration which would hold the actual app data and then an "export" configuration to handle your exports. The entities in the export configuration should be subentities of you main entities. That way they will inherit all the attributes and relationships of the main entity. Assign the main configuration to your main store and the export configuration to an export file.

When you want to export data, you would clone the main entities to their subentities in the export configuration and then save them to the export persistent store. To import the data, just reverse the process.